# задача №66 не могу правильно создать код

Tags: python

```
summ = 0
b = int(input())
while b != 0:
    summ += b 
    b = int(input())
print(summ)
```

[image: задача 66]

Comment: В чем сложность то?

Comment: в чем вопрос? Зачем ты постишь сюда три задачи, хотя требуется только одна? Этим ты проявляешь неуважение к тем людям, у которых просишь помощи.

Comment: сорян , просто не знаю как написать код( Выше код который я попытался слепить

Comment: СПАСИБО nyekitka!!!

Comment: @MaksoniCH если ответ помог, то отметьте его, пожалуйста, как верный с помощью галочки слева сбоку от ответа

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```py
summ = 0
true_summ = summ
price = ' '
demo = ' '
while price:
    demo = input()
    if len(demo) == 0:
        break
    price = int(demo)
    summ = summ + price

if (summ / 2) < 2.5:
    # меньше
    pass
else:
    # больше
    pass

print(int(summ))
print(int(true_summ))
```

округлить не могу.

Answer (score 0):

Преобразование пустой строки к int ведёт к ошибке, поэтому сразу писать `b = int(input())` - неверно. Кроме того, мало ли какой-то товар стоит 0 центов (в реальности маловероятно, но в условиях задачи это не оговорено). Соответственно программа может завершиться после нуля, хотя нужно завершать её после пустой строки. Это нужно сделать следующим образом:

```
amount = 0      # общая сумма товаров
s = input()     # строка в которую мы будем считывать из консоли
while s != '':
    amount += int(s)
    s = input()
print(amount)
```